# Data fetched from Firebase using useSWR returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I am following a course where I am fetching data from Firebase using `useSWR` and using it to set the state. However when I try to console log the data, I get undefined and the screen shows loading. Is there any reason to this. I even copied the exact same code the instructor uses (except the API link).

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';

function LastSalesPage() {
  const [sales, setSales] = useState();
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    'https://nextjs-2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/sales.json'
  );

  console.log('Data:', data);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const transformedSales = [];

      for (const key in data) {
        transformedSales.push({
          id: key,
          username: data[key].username,
          volume: data[key].volume,
        });
      }

      setSales(transformedSales);
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (error) {
    return <p>Failed to load.</p>;
  }

  if (!data || !sales) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {sales.map((sale) => (
        <li key={sale.id}>
          {sale.username} - ${sale.volume}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default LastSalesPage;
```

Comment: Are you defining the fetcher method globally? Can you share the fetcher's code?

Comment: There was no mention of adding fetcher globally on the course so I didn't add it. However adding a fetcher function seemed to solve the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accordingly to the official docs -

> the useSWR hook accepts a key string and a fetcher function. key is a unique identifier of the data (normally the API URL) and will be passed to fetcher. fetcher can be any asynchronous function which returns the data, you can use the native fetch or tools like Axios.

So it seems that you simply don't pass any fetcher there.

Try defining hook like so:

```
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    'https://nextjs-2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/sales.json',
    fetcher
  );
```

Alternatively you can wrap your app with `<SWRConfig>` and set fetcher globaly, that would be available for all children components within that wrapper/context. And I supposed this is exactly what you were lacking in your code and couldn't use the hook without explicitly passing a fetcher.

E.g.

```
function App () {
  return (
    <SWRConfig 
      value={{
        fetcher: (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
      }}
    >
      <Example />
    </SWRConfig>
  )
}
```

So with having this in place your code example would work without passing fetcher parameter and this is exactly why it is optional

Comment: OP is probably defining the [fetcher globally](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration), otherwise they would get an error complaining about it.

Comment: Well then the question needs more context.

Comment: @JSEvgeny Adding a fetcher seemed to solve the problem. I didn't consider adding it before because the instructor said that it wasn't necessary in that case, as it would use fetch by default. No mention of it on his GitHub code either.

Comment: @JSEvgeny You were right, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const { data : userData, error: errorUserData } = useSWR(
    'https://nextjs-2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/sales.json'
  );
```

And your full file (working, tested by me):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';

function LastSalesPage() {
  const [sales, setSales] = useState();
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const { data: userData, error: userDataError } = useSWR(
    'https://nextjs-2021-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/sales.json'
  );



  if (userDataError) {
    return <p>Failed to load.</p>;
  }

  if (!userData) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
  if (userData){
  let transformedSales = [];

      for (const key in userData) {
        transformedSales.push({
          id: key,
          username: userData[key].username,
          volume: userData[key].volume,
        });
  }
  console.log(userData, transformedSales)
  let sales = transformedSales
  return (
    <ul>
      {sales.map((sale) => (
        <li key={sale.id}>
          {sale.username} - ${sale.volume}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  }
}

export default LastSalesPage;
```

**P.S** don't use useEffect() hook (react hook) for data fetching, useSWR works perfect for this purpose.

**P.S (2)** you don't need ***fetcher*** to fetch data with no special params, so just = useSWR('/api/path')

Explanation about **fetcher**: if you check [official docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/options), fetcher is *optional* param. "The fetcher here is an async function that accepts the key of SWR, and returns the data" - from [here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/data-fetching). I can't really explain why your code *with fetcher works*, but I shared your modified code with clear logic.

Comment: Can you explain why my code didn't work. I tried adding a fetcher function and it seemed to work. However you just said that fetcher isn't needed to fetch data. I am a bit lost

Comment: Answered in the post

Comment: Fetcher is optional because `Note that fetcher can be omitted from the parameters if it's provided globally.`, but it MUST be provided either way